# Codekit ignores .jshintrc

Tags: javascript, amd, jshint, codekit

As is fairly common these days, I use AMD modules to organize my JS. So I have a .jshintrc configured in each project accordingly:

```
{
    "predef": [
        "define",
        "require"
    ]
}
```

On the command line, running jshint gives clear output. However Codekit seems to be ignoring the jshint when it runs, complaining about 'define' etc.

How can I make Codekit respect a .jshintrc file?

Comment: Any solutions to this so far? Having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry @IvanTorres after having a few issues with CodeKit and approaching the author with no response, I gave up and now use `gulp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Custom Globals` is a CSV list that is used for both JSHint and JSLint.

It is located here:

`CodeKit.app` → `[Select Your Project]` → `Project Settings` / `[Gear Icon]` → `Syntax Checkers` → `Custom Globals`

Yours would look like this:

[image: CodeKit -> Project Settings -> Syntax Checkers -> Custom Globals]

I tested it with "`app, angular`" and it worked like a charm.